# Waiting for a get request to complete

Tags: javascript, jquery

Alright, so I am making something that will make an account. I have this function that checks if the username exists, and if it isn't it returns false.

Then I have another function calling it, but it is automatically going to the else statement and not waiting for the get request to complete. How would I make it wait until it gets a response?

```
var accountPassword = "accToGetTix"

function checkUsername(username){
    $.get("http://www.roblox.com/UserCheck/DoesUsernameExist?username=" + username, function(data){
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            return data.sucess; // true = taken , false = not taken
        });
    });
};
function makeNewAccount(accountName){
    if (checkUsername(accountName) == false){
        signupWindow = window.open("http://www.roblox.com/login/signup.aspx");
        signupWindow.$("#SignupUsername").val(accountName)
        signupWindow.$("#SignupPassword").val(accountPassword)
        signupWindow.$("#SignupPasswordConfirm").val(accountPassword)
        signupWindow.$('#birthdayMonthSelect option[value="0"]').prop('selected', true)
        signupWindow.$('#birthdayDaySelect option[value="0"]').prop('selected', true)
        signupWindow.$('#birthdayYearSelect option[value="25"]').prop('selected', true)
        signupWindow.$('.gender-circle').click();
    } else {
        return true; // true = account taken , false = not taken
    }
}

makeNewAccount('asdf205m0');
```

Comment: You can't return from an async calll... you need to use a callback.

Comment: You should have your conditional INSIDE the $.get success callback

Comment: and you've got a typo: *data.success

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by updating your code like following

```
function checkUsername(username, callback) {
    $.get("http://www.roblox.com/UserCheck/DoesUsernameExist?username=" + username, function(data) {
        callback(data.sucess); // true = taken , false = not taken
    });
};


function makeNewAccount(accountName) {
    checkUsername(accountName, function(response) {
        if (response == false) {
            signupWindow = window.open("http://www.roblox.com/login/signup.aspx");
            signupWindow.$("#SignupUsername").val(accountName)
            signupWindow.$("#SignupPassword").val(accountPassword)
            signupWindow.$("#SignupPasswordConfirm").val(accountPassword)
            signupWindow.$('#birthdayMonthSelect option[value="0"]').prop('selected', true)
            signupWindow.$('#birthdayDaySelect option[value="0"]').prop('selected', true)
            signupWindow.$('#birthdayYearSelect option[value="25"]').prop('selected', true)
            signupWindow.$('.gender-circle').click();
        } else {
            return true; // true = account taken , false = not taken
        }

    });

}
```

Comment: Please take that `document.ready()` out of your callback. It's pointless and confusing.

Comment: nevermind, it worked. I misspelled success as sucess

Answer (score 1):

You can't `return` from an async call. You need to use callbacks. A little refactor and you can make it work:

```
function checkUsername(username, callback){
    $.get("http://www.roblox.com/UserCheck/DoesUsernameExist?username=" + username, function(data){
        if (callback) callback(data.sucess); // true = taken , false = not taken
    });
};

function makeNewAccount(accountName){
    checkUsername(accountName, function(response) {
        if (response === false) {
            signupWindow = window.open("http://www.roblox.com/login/signup.aspx");
            signupWindow.$("#SignupUsername").val(accountName)
            signupWindow.$("#SignupPassword").val(accountPassword)
            signupWindow.$("#SignupPasswordConfirm").val(accountPassword)
            signupWindow.$('#birthdayMonthSelect option[value="0"]').prop('selected', true)
            signupWindow.$('#birthdayDaySelect option[value="0"]').prop('selected', true)
            signupWindow.$('#birthdayYearSelect option[value="25"]').prop('selected', true)
            signupWindow.$('.gender-circle').click();
        } else {
            return true; // true = account taken , false = not taken
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: To be technically correct: You CAN `return` from an async call, it just won't do what OP expected it to.

Answer (score 0):

you will have to use the .done function, like that:

```
var accountPassword = "accToGetTix"

function checkUsername(username){
    $.get("http://www.roblox.com/UserCheck/DoesUsernameExist", {
        "username": username
    }).done(function(data){
        if (data.success) {
            alert("this username already exists");
        } else {
            makeNewAccount(username);
        }
    });
};

function makeNewAccount(accountName){
    if (checkUsername(accountName) == false){
        signupWindow = window.open("http://www.roblox.com/login/signup.aspx");
        signupWindow.$("#SignupUsername").val(accountName)
        signupWindow.$("#SignupPassword").val(accountPassword)
        signupWindow.$("#SignupPasswordConfirm").val(accountPassword)
        signupWindow.$('#birthdayMonthSelect option[value="0"]').prop('selected', true)
        signupWindow.$('#birthdayDaySelect option[value="0"]').prop('selected', true)
        signupWindow.$('#birthdayYearSelect option[value="25"]').prop('selected', true)
        signupWindow.$('.gender-circle').click();
    } else {
        return true; // true = account taken , false = not taken
    }
}
```

you can find more information here: https://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/

I'm not sure about what your get call returns, so, if you'll have to adapt your code if needed. Use console.log(data), inside the .done function if needed too. :p

**EDIT:**

the $.get function in jQuery makes an Assynchronous http request to the specified URL. Assynchronous means that the code will not necessarily run in a linear order by waiting the request to complete in order to pass to the next code line.

The javascript code can be categorized in two types: Synchronous and Assynchronous. Let me show you an example.

This is a synchronous code:

```
function IWillRunFirst(){
    console.log("first!");
}

IWillRunFirst();

alert("I am the second");

var someElement = $("#justAnElement");

someElement.addClass("foo");

console.log("finish");

//this results:
//    "first!"
//    "I am the second"
//    "finish"
```

This code will run in the exactly same order that it was wrote. Now here an example of assynchronous code:

```
function IWillRunFirstButMyResponseWillGetLate(){
    $.get("someUrl", {
        "myUrlParameter": "foo"
    }).done(function(requestResponse){
        console.log("Howdy! Did I got late?");
    });
}

IWillRunFirstButMyResponseWillGetLate();

alert("I am the second");

var someElement = $("#justAnElement");

someElement.addClass("foo");

console.log("finished");
```

The result of the above code can be:

```
"I am the second"
"finished"
"Howdy! Did I got late?"
```

Remember: Ajax calls are ***ALWAYS*** assynchronous ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think the cleanest way is to use promises object through jquery deffered https://api.jquery.com/jquery.deferred/, along with it u need to use jquery $.get method which returns promises. https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/. 
I can  share the code examples, but going through this concept will benefit you more .